# Jmeter regex extractor create 3 variables instead of 1

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to make a jmeter extractor that just takes everything between two quotes.

[image: A picture of my extractor]

Instead of matching and assigning the characters between the quotes to the variable with the name specified, that variable is empty and three others are created.  The last one is what I would have liked the first one to look like.

[image: Picture of results]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated the answer with more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `Template` that is `$1$` without quotes, OR us `$0$` extracting with quotes (`"`):

> [The template](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) used to create a string from the matches found.
>   This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups
>   within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is:
>   '$1$' to refer to group 1, '$2$' to refer to group 2, etc. $0$ refers
>   to whatever the entire expression matches. So, if you have in response
>   word “economics” and search for regular expression “(ec)(onomics)” and
>   apply template $2$$1$ than in output variable you will receive
>   “onomicsec”.

```
newTest=connected  #got group 1 ($1$)
newTest_g=1        # total groups
newTest_g0="connected" # group $0$
newTest_g1=connected   # group $1$
```

[image]